# How to know whether the Function is used/ Checkbox button is clicked in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, database-performance

Sorry for the unclear title and explanation, there's a simple things I wanna to test with. In the program, I create a function which hide/show certain records. The function used the HTML form id as a parameter to do the if-else statement, what I gonna to do is having another if-else in the html there. Maybe certain codes below will make you guys understanding what am I saying, thanks in advanced...

Function

```
function display(){

    var ischecked = true;
    var f = document.frm;
    ischecked = (f.filter.checked);

    if(!ischecked){

        for (var i= 1; i< tblData.rows.length; i++)
            {

                if (tblData.rows[i].cells[9].innerHTML =='<FONT size=1><B>DRAFT</B></FONT>' )
                {
                    //tblData.rows[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
                    tblData.rows[i].style.display = 'none';

                }
            } 

    } else {            
            for (var i= 1; i< tblData.rows.length; i++)
            {
                    tblData.rows[i].style.display = 'block';

            } 
    }
}
```

related HTML code

```
<div><input type="checkbox" name="filter" id="checkboxID" onclick="display();"/><FONT class="LinkFontClass">Sample</FONT></div>
```

Stuck here

```
<% if (function(activated)) {%>
              Then do something</TD>
              <% } else {%>
                do something</TD>
                <%} %>
```

The purposed to do this is that I dun want to load the database for the data, again and again when click the checkBox. I try at where I stuck there, it doesn't go through else statement. Need some hints and advised, appreciated^^

Comment: Don't open your question with an apology for unclear explanations. First, practically, it means the excerpt shown on the questions list shows nothing useful, and second, make the explanation something you don't feel you have to apologize for. :-)

Comment: *"The purposed to do this is that I dun want"*  What does 'dun' mean?  It is not any word in English that I recognize.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: It is English, actually. :-) It means brown (well, that's one of its oldest meanings, goes back to Old English more than 1,000 years ago, probably borrowed from Old Saxon). (And probably not the word 薛源少 was looking for.)

Comment: well, I try to...thanks for the advised

Comment: First of all what you require ? The above code itself will work . Except for the document.frm thing

Comment: Erm, I just want to know if there a better way to do these?
like a HashTable of something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple jquery for this

```
    $("#id").click(function(){

    // Do something
alert("Clicked");
    });
```

HTML part:

```
<div id="id">click Me</div>
```

When user will click "Click Me" it will alert cliked.

Answer (score 0):

Attach an event handler to filter that calls ischecked(); function. 
Or simply do it this way:

```
<div><input type="checkbox" name="filter" id="checkboxID" onclick="display(this.checked);"/><FONT class="LinkFontClass">Sample</FONT></div>


function display(ischecked){   
if(!ischecked){
...
```

Explanation: 
if  `document.frm.filter.checked` works, then apperently "checked" is an attribute of filter, so by putting it into the onclick function with `display(this.checked)` you directly get the checked attributes value and give it to `function display(ischecked)`. This way you can directly use the value in the funciton.

Comment: erm, can u describe a bit?

Answer (score 0):

If you are generate table content then you can add `class` (or parameter like `draft`) to the table rows. And then hide rows with that `class`.
See it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2J7y/).